# Bootstrap: Reducing NavBar width and all its drop down option panels and text size

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap css for Nav Bar and it comes up very fine.
But the width appears to be big and I want to reduce it ( also ensure that it gets equally reduced/adjusted in other viewports also) and also reduce the options panels/text size that comes under the Nav Bar dropdown.

I'm using the following css class

navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse

and the Nav Bar is coming in black ( which is giving the wow effect) and something that is needed but all the options under dropdown is coming as white. How to make this white background to black? Any bootstrap class already in place?

If navbar-inverse can make the top nav bar as black then there must be some class to provide the same effect for the dropdown panel options under the same Nav Bar

I want to avoid custom css at this point to achieve this.

Thanks,
Faraz

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to change anything unless you want to create a custom css file, or edit the bootstrap css files.

If you are looking for something very simple, i have found this fantastic

http://pikock.github.io/bootstrap-magic/app/index.html#!/editor